# Black screen and airplane mode on a ASUS TUF FX504 laptop with a replaced screen

Tags: laptop, memory, motherboard, black-screen-of-death, airplane-mode

Namely, when I press the button to turn it on, the LED on the keyboard lights up, the screen turns from some shade of dark green to black, the cpu and gpu slowly start to heat up.

The fans turn on and work moderately, the battery is there as well as the CMOS, the disk was there and RAM but screen is black.

The problem is that the image is black all the time, and after a while the airplane mode light turns on on the laptop.

What I tried:

- Turned off all power sources (AC adapter and battery), held the power button for 40 seconds and tried to turn it on again - the problem was not solved.
- I tried to change the RAM - I used 16GB ddr4 3200 Mhz and 8GB 2133 Mhz - the problem was not solved.
- I disconnected the battery, tried to turn it on only with the AC adapter - unsuccessfully.
- I tried to start on battery only - unsuccessful.
- I tried to turn on the laptop via the HDMI cable via the smart TV (I had previously disconnected the laptop's display after turning off all the power supplies) - unsuccessfully.

The laptop was bought after a person sent me a video of the laptop being turned on - the Asus logo was visible. I would also like to point out that it was purchased without a display, I bought the display afterwards, it is full HD LED slim 30pin Asus display.

Comment: `video of the laptop being turned on` ... how do you know that it is the same laptop?

Comment: SN on laptop and motherboard is same

Comment: that is not an assurance that the laptop was functional when it was shipped ... the seller could have made the video before attempting to repair a problem, and failing

Comment: Seller is 100% safe, with over 1000 sales and all of them are succesful sales. This is not first time that I am dealing with this person but it is first time that I am facing problem. If laptop is issue than fans will spin all time, and they are in silen mode and than after a while they start spining. Curen measured with multimeter are fine, but black screen and airplane mode are issue.